# Reading BerkleyDB files from python: `\x01\x0b\x88\x0c\x01`?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

**This question in a nutshell: what do `\x04++HLMh7EjP3ILSfF\x00` and**

```
'\x01\x0b\x88\x0c\x01-\x10\x02\x06!\x05"\x05#\n$\x0c\'\x0e%\x0b\x01&\x02\'\x06(\n\x00\x00'
```

**mean?**

Hi all,

I'm trying to read palm pre 2 database files. Some information is available [in the documentation](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/mojo/db8.html), but not enough for me to clearly understand the format.

Using the `file` command, I learnt that the format was `objects.db: Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)`.

Trying to open the database directly using `bsddb.open()` didn't work; I had to use

```
>>> env = bsddb.db.DBEnv()
>>> env.open(None, bsddb.db.DB_CREATE | bsddb.db.DB_INIT_MPOOL)
>>> internal_db = bsddb.db.DB(env)
>>> internal_db.open('C:\objects.db', 'objects.db', bsddb.db.DB_BTREE, bsddb.db.DB_RDONLY)
```

Now I've open the database, but the keys and values are encoded in a format which I don't understand: for example, here are some keys: `'\x04++HMvu4v2GZbo1Ox\x00', '\x04++HMwBSPR8Zvwkt5\x00', '\x04++HMwF4OJ0R+WeSS\x00'`, and a value:

```
'\x01\x0b\xb7\r\x00\x05\xee\x89\x10\x029\x060\x04\x00/\x03\x04++HQqD0wWr_hZP75\x00\x00 \x02"\x06\x00$\x04inbox\x001\x02+\x04+33626320868\x00\x00%\x0e\x00\x00\x01.0\x19\xb3\x10&\x04Ok\x00-\rM\\/\x892\n:\r\x00\x05\xee\x89\'\x04sms\x003\n(\x04successful\x00.\rM\\/\x89\x00'
```

I tried to decode it from utf8, but I didn't get any convincing results. Do you recognize which encoding is being used? I don't understand the `native byte-order` part of the output of the `file` command, could it be related to this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is that db supposed to contain?

Comment: native byte order (little-endian or big-endian) could quite possibly cause this problem. what you're seeing is almost certainly binary data and not human-readable information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Educated guess

From simple inspection, The message is probably "sms successful", with a phone number:

> > > unicode(s, errors='ignore')
> > >       u'\x01\x0b\r\x00\x05\x10\x029\x060\x04\x00/\x03\x04++HQqD0wWr_hZP75\x00\x00 \x02"\x06\x00$\x04inbox\x001\x02+\x04+33626320868\x00\x00%\x0e\x00\x00\x01.0\x19\x10&\x04Ok\x00-\rM\/2\n:\r\x00\x05\'\x04sms\x003\n(\x04successful\x00.\rM\/\x00'

I think the other characters are binary data.

#### Encodings

Decoding it did not help - Both chardet and BeautifulSoup detects this as `windows-1252`:

```
>>> s=u'\x01\x0b\xb7\r\x00\x05\xee\u2030\x10\x029\x060\x04\x00/\x03\x04++HQqD0wWr_hZP75\x00\x00 \x02"\x06\x00$\x04inbox\x001\x02+\x04+33626320868\x00\x00%\x0e\x00\x00\x01.0\x19\xb3\x10&\x04Ok\x00-\rM\\/\u20302\n:\r\x00\x05\xee\u2030\'\x04sms\x003\n(\x04successful\x00.\rM\\/\u2030\x00'
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.originalEncoding
'windows-1252'
>>> chardet.detect(s)
{'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
```

However, the 1252 decoding gives nothing meaningful:

```
>>> s.decode('windows-1252')
u'\x01\x0b\xb7\r\x00\x05\xee\u2030\x10\x029\x060\x04\x00/\x03\x04++HQqD0wWr_hZP75\x00\x00 \x02"\x06\x00$\x04inbox\x001\x02+\x04+33626320868\x00\x00%\x0e\x00\x00\x01.0\x19\xb3\x10&\x04Ok\x00-\rM\\/\u20302\n:\r\x00\x05\xee\u2030\'\x04sms\x003\n(\x04successful\x00.\rM\\/\u2030\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I eventually found in the doc that the database uses a proprietary encoding.

Comment: @Clément interesting - can you tell us more?

Comment: I don't know much more, except this: from version 1.* to version 2.0, Palm moved from sqlite3 to what they call db8. The data is accessible on the device through an API, which they once said they would open-source, but nothing happened since then. The db format itsleft is Berkeley DB, but the encoding is one they designed themselves, and the decoding code is not yet available, it seems. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PalmDB](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PalmDB) or [dbsql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbsql) instead of `bsddb`.